# Выборка блока по критериям кратко

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть 2 блока "SEARCH INVENTORY" и "сетка с товаром"

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Направьте на пусть истинный, как по нажатию кнопки организовать поиск. Для примера сделаем выборку по одному элементу "make" and "model".

```
<div class="disc">Make</div>
<select id="Make">
   <option>BMW</option>
</select>
<div class="disc">Model</div>
  <select id="Model"> 
     <option>x6</option>
 </select>
```

2) Получаю данные выбранного select

```
 var make = document.getElementById("Make");
 var model = document.getElementById("Model");
 var valueMake = make.value;
 var valueModel = model.value;
```

3) Объект сетки товара выглядит сл. образом:

```
<div class="photo-car">
<img src="img/kia.jpg" alt="car" />
 <div class="price">$45.000</div>
<div class="make">BMW</div>
<div class="model">X5</div>
```

3.1) Сравниваю с текстом в блоках. Если совпадают - ничего не делаю, если не совпадают, добавляю класс .hideCarBlock { display:none}. Ищу все блоки car на странице 
Спасибо всем за помощь!

```
<script>
    var make = document.getElementById("Make");
    var model = document.getElementById("Model");
    var valueMake = make.value;
    var valueModel = model.value;  
    var carBlock = document.querySelectorAll('.car');
    var carMake = document.querySelectorAll('.make');

    for (var i=0; i<carBlock.length;i++) { 

        if (carMake[i].innerHTML == valueMake) {
            console.log("dadad");
        } else {
            carBlock[i].style.display="none";
        }     
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Мне кажется, такое на сервере надо делать. На клиенте идет только сбор параметров для поиска

Comment: Это обычная верстка с доп. js

Comment: Коллеги, прошу помочь в решении данного вопроса

Comment: Пишу с телефона, поэтому только так: 1) `querySelectorAll("Make")` - это не правильно, нет такого тега "make". 2) make.value - это обращение к аттрибуту value. `option` у Вас не содержит этого атрибута

Comment: @Дмытрык , 1)  изменил 
    <div class="Make">BMW</div>  querySelectorAll(".Make")
2) 
   var valueMake = make.value;
выводит значения options